# Is there a way to reduce decimal places in JavaScript and get a number output in one step?

Tags: javascript, numbers, tofixed

I'm a beginner in Javascript. I know the command `.toFixed()` reduces the decimal places after the comma to the number you write in parenthesis. However, this command turns the number into a string, and so if we wanted to use that information as a number we'd need to use `Number()` to turn that into a number.

Is there a command in JS that reduces the decimal places after the comma already returning a number value to us all in only one step?

Many thanks

Comment: You can use the unary `+`: `+(2.345).toFixed(6)`. For more information, see the duplicate target.

Comment: @InSync `+(2.345).toFixed(6)` would just turn the number back in `2.345`. This is because `2.345` is the same as `2.345000`

Comment: @Reyno I know, that's just an example.

Comment: Thanks, just tested here and it works!